# how to fit too wide and long table (one table) into two pages

Tags: latex, pdflatex

I have a table which too long and wide as well. I tried to fit it into Latex but not fit correctly by using packages `rotating`' and `tabularx`' (landscape page). I do not have the experience to fit this long and wide table into Latex, which I would like to see this table on landscape two pages as there are more details should be clear to read them. 
Here the code:

```
\documentclass{book} % thesis class
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption} % optional

\usepackage{ragged2e}


\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}
\caption{Long wide table}
\label{tab:margParams}
\centering
%\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{Xllllllllllll}
  \hline
& \multicolumn{6}{c}{\textbf{Group 0}} & \multicolumn{6}{c}{\textbf{Group 1}}  \\
  & Posterior Mean &  95\% HPD Interval & SD & Bias & MSE & Coverage & Posterior Mean &  95\% HPD Interval & SD & Bias & MSE & Coverage \\
  \hline
  &  \multicolumn{12}{c}{\textbf{Albumin}} \\
  E[Albumin:Intercept] & 3.69 & (3.64, 3.74) & 3.96$\times 10^{-3}$ & 1.48$\times 10^{-4}$ & 6.17$\times 10^{-4}$ & 0.96 & 3.38 & (3.28, 3.48)& 4.16$\times 10^{-3}$ & -1.12$\times 10^{-2}$ & 3.80$\times 10^{-3}$ & 0.89 \\
  E[Albumin:slope] & -6.85$\times 10^{-3}$ & (-9.17, -4.51)$\times 10^{-3}$ & 3.38$\times 10^{-4}$ & -2.28$\times 10^{-5}$ & 1.81$\times 10^{-6}$ & 0.89 & -1.42$\times 10^{-2}$ &( -1.91, -0.94)$\times 10^{-2}$ & 2.93$\times 10^{-4}$ & 1.92$\times 10^{-4}$ & 7.06$\times 10^{-6}$ & 0.91\\
  SD[Albumin:Intercept] & 2.64$\times 10^{-1}$ & (2.23, 3.07)$\times 10^{-1}$ & 1.73$\times 10^{-3}$ & 4.21$\times 10^{-4}$ & 3.81$\times 10^{-4}$ & 0.95 & 2.58$\times 10^{-1}$ &( 1.74, 3.43)$\times 10^{-1}$ & 3.30$\times 10^{-3}$ & -6.18$\times 10^{-3}$ & 2.21$\times 10^{-3}$ & 0.95 \\
  Corr[Albumin:Intercept,Albumin:slope] & 6.23$\times 10^{-3}$ & (-5.28,5.63)$\times 10^{-1}$ & 2.30$\times 10^{-2}$ & 7.09$\times 10^{-2}$ & 2.05$\times 10^{-2}$ & 0.99 & -2.23$\times 10^{-3}$ & (-6.72, 6.89)$\times 10^{-1}$ & 1.41$\times 10^{-2}$ & 6.24$\times 10^{-2}$ & 1.97$\times 10^{-2}$ & 0.99 \\
  Corr[Albumin:Intercept,log(Bilirubin):Intercept] & -1.79$\times 10^{-1}$ & (-3.54, -0.03)$\times 10^{-1}$ & 7.12$\times 10^{-3}$ & 1.72$\times 10^{-2}$ & 9.32 $\times 10^{-3}$& 0.95 & -1.80$\times 10^{-1}$ &( -5.11, 1.60)$\times 10^{-1}$ & 1.09$\times 10^{-2}$ & 1.65$\times 10^{-2}$ & 2.10$\times 10^{-2}$ & 0.99 \\
  Corr[Albumin:Intercept,log(Bilirubin):slope] & 1.74$\times 10^{-1}$ & (-1.72, 5.15)$\times 10^{-1}$ & 1.31$\times 10^{-2}$ & -3.70$\times 10^{-2}$ & 2.17$\times 10^{-2}$ & 0.96 & 5.92$\times 10^{-2}$ & (-6.01, 6.96)$\times 10^{-1}$ & 1.39$\times 10^{-2}$ & -1.52$\times 10^{-1}$ & 5.51$\times 10^{-2}$ & 0.99 \\
  Corr[Albumin:Intercept,Platelet:Intercept] & 1.43$\times 10^{-1}$ & (-0.33, 3.17)$\times 10^{-1}$ & 8.32$\times 10^{-3}$ & -4.84$\times 10^{-2}$ & 1.06$\times 10^{-2}$ & 0.90& 1.40$\times 10^{-1}$ & (-1.92, 4.65)$\times 10^{-1}$ & 1.09$\times 10^{-2}$ & -5.15$\times 10^{-2}$ & 3.09$\times 10^{-2}$ & 0.92 \\
  Corr[Albumin:Intercept,Platelet:slope] & 6.04$\times 10^{-2}$ & (-1.19, 2.40)$\times 10^{-1}$ & 8.06$\times 10^{-3}$ & -4.90$\times 10^{-2}$ & 1.15$\times 10^{-2}$ &0.89 & 3.21$\times 10^{-2}$ & (-3.10, 3.76)$\times 10^{-1}$ & 1.16$\times 10^{-2}$ & -7.73$\times 10^{-2}$ & 3.31$\times 10^{-2}$ & 0.90 \\
  Corr[Albumin:Intercept,Blood Vessel Malformations:Intercept] & -2.70$\times 10^{-1}$ & (-4.92, -0.43)$\times 10^{-1}$ & 8.93$\times 10^{-3}$ & 7.88$\times 10^{-2}$ & 1.93$\times 10^{-2}$ & 0.89 & -2.95$\times 10^{-1}$ & (-6.65, 0.93)$\times 10^{-1}$ & 1.22$\times 10^{-2}$ & 5.35$\times 10^{-2}$ & 3.12$\times 10^{-2}$ & 0.96 \\
  SD[Albumin:slope] & 3.62$\times 10^{-3}$ & (0.85, 7.22)$\times 10^{-3}$ & 5.89$\times 10^{-4}$ & -4.14$\times 10^{-3}$ & 2.50$\times 10^{-5}$ & 0.47 & 3.30$\times 10^{-3}$ & (0.07, 8.15)$\times 10^{-3}$ & 3.60$\times 10^{-4}$ & -4.46$\times 10^{-3}$ & 2.69$\times 10^{-5}$ & 0.54 \\
  Corr[Albumin:slope,log(Bilirubin):Intercept] & -2.98$\times 10^{-2}$ & (-5.60,5.03)$\times 10^{-1}$ & 2.38$\times 10^{-2}$ & -3.14$\times 10^{-2}$ & 1.85$\times 10^{-2}$ & 0.99 & -1.05$\times 10^{-2}$ & (-6.73, 6.52)$\times 10^{-1}$ & 1.33$\times 10^{-2}$ & -1.21$\times 10^{-2}$ & 1.60$\times 10^{-2}$ & 0.99 \\
  Corr[Albumin:slope,log(Bilirubin):slope] & -3.73$\times 10^{-2}$ &(-6.30, 5.68)$\times 10^{-1}$ & 2.30$\times 10^{-2}$ & 1.96$\times 10^{-1}$ & 5.31$\times 10^{-2}$ & 0.99 & -1.76$\times 10^{-2}$ & (-7.77, 7.50)$\times 10^{-1}$ & 1.24$\times 10^{-2}$ & 2.15$\times 10^{-1}$ & 5.62$\times 10^{-2}$ & 0.99 \\
  Corr[Albumin:slope,Platelet:Intercept] & -1.74$\times 10^{-1}$ & (-6.87, 3.65)$\times 10^{-1}$ & 3.11$\times 10^{-2}$ & 8.34$\times 10^{-2}$ & 3.09$\times 10^{-2}$ & 0.98 & -7.37$\times 10^{-2}$ & (-7.17, 5.89)$\times 10^{-1}$ & 1.40$\times 10^{-2}$ & 1.83$\times 10^{-1}$ & 5.04$\times 10^{-2}$ & 0.99 \\
  Corr[Albumin:slope,Platelet:slope] & -1.42$\times 10^{-1}$ & (-6.35,3.76)$\times 10^{-1}$ & 2.83$\times 10^{-2}$ & 1.18$\times 10^{-1}$ & 3.45$\times 10^{-2}$ & 0.99 & -9.37$\times 10^{-2}$ & (-7.17, 5.56)$\times 10^{-1}$ & 1.53$\times 10^{-2}$ & 1.67$\times 10^{-1}$ & 4.91$\times 10^{-2}$ & 0.99 \\
  Corr[Albumin:slope,Blood Vessel Malformations:Intercept] & 8.20$\times 10^{-2}$ & (-4.90, 6.36)$\times 10^{-1}$ & 2.84$\times 10^{-2}$ & -1.45$\times 10^{-1}$ & 4.16$\times 10^{-2}$ & 0.99 & 5.78$\times 10^{-2}$ &( -6.50, 7.41)$\times 10^{-1}$ & 1.52$\times 10^{-2}$ & -1.69$\times 10^{-1}$ & 4.78$\times 10^{-2}$ & 0.99 \\
  &  \multicolumn{12}{c}{\textbf{log(Bilirubin)}} \\
  E[log(Bilirubin):Intercept] & 2.06$\times 10^{-2}$ &( -1.04, 1.44)$\times 10^{-1}$ & 4.11$\times 10^{-3}$ & -7.45$\times 10^{-4}$ & 4.30$\times 10^{-3}$ & 0.94 & 1.24 & (0.99, 1.49) & 8.48$\times 10^{-3}$ & 6.19$\times 10^{-3}$ & 1.85$\times 10^{-2}$ & 0.95 \\
  E[log(Bilirubin):slope] & 1.03$\times 10^{-2}$ & (0.72, 1.35)$\times 10^{-2}$ & 1.30$\times 10^{-4}$ & 3.72$\times 10^{-4}$ & 2.83$\times 10^{-6}$ & 0.94 & 2.35$\times 10^{-2}$ &( 1.70, 2.99)$\times 10^{-2}$ & 3.26$\times 10^{-4}$ & -3.32$\times 10^{-4}$ & 1.26$\times 10^{-5}$ & 0.92 \\
  SD[log(Bilirubin):Intercept] & 8.53$\times 10^{-1}$ &(7.62,9.47)$\times 10^{-1}$ & 3.13$\times 10^{-3}$ & 7.79$\times 10^{-3}$ & 2.18$\times 10^{-3}$ & 0.96 & 8.43$\times 10^{-1}$ & (0.67, 1.03 )& 6.08$\times 10^{-3}$ & -1.90$\times 10^{-3}$ & 9.30$\times 10^{-3}$ & 0.93 \\
  Corr[log(Bilirubin):Intercept,log(Bilirubin):slope] & -1.30$\times 10^{-1}$ & (-4.31, 1.94)$\times 10^{-1}$ & 1.16$\times 10^{-2}$ & 4.44$\times 10^{-2}$ & 1.89$\times 10^{-2}$ & 0.98 & -5.56$\times 10^{-2}$ & (-6.61, 5.91)$\times 10^{-1}$ & 1.34$\times 10^{-2}$ & 1.19$\times 10^{-1}$ & 4.36$\times 10^{-2}$ & 0.99 \\
  Corr[log(Bilirubin):Intercept,Platelet:Intercept] & 2.36$\times 10^{-1}$ & (0.99, 3.72)$\times 10^{-1}$ & 4.62$\times 10^{-3}$ & -1.11$\times 10^{-2}$ & 5.76$\times 10^{-3}$ & 0.93 & 2.10$\times 10^{-1}$ & (-0.62, 4.74)$\times 10^{-1}$ & 8.78$\times 10^{-3}$ & -3.73$\times 10^{-2}$ & 1.98$\times 10^{-2}$ & 0.96 \\
  Corr[log(Bilirubin):Intercept,Platelet:slope] & -1.77$\times 10^{-1}$ & (-3.19, -0.32)$\times 10^{-1}$ & 4.72$\times 10^{-3}$ & 9.71$\times 10^{-3}$ & 5.49$\times 10^{-3}$ & 0.95& -1.66$\times 10^{-1}$ & (-4.43, 1.16)$\times 10^{-1}$ & 9.22$\times 10^{-3}$ & 2.09$\times 10^{-2}$ & 1.74$\times 10^{-2}$ & 0.97 \\
  Corr[log(Bilirubin):Intercept,Blood Vessel Malformations:Intercept] & 2.85$\times 10^{-1}$ & (0.96, 4.71)$\times 10^{-1}$ & 6.30$\times 10^{-3}$ & 1.49$\times 10^{-2}$ & 8.52$\times 10^{-3}$ & 0.94 & 2.41$\times 10^{-1}$ & (-0.93, 5.64)$\times 10^{-1}$ & 1.07$\times 10^{-2}$ & -2.95$\times 10^{-2}$ & 2.74$\times 10^{-2}$ & 0.94\\
  SD[log(Bilirubin):slope] & 1.17$\times 10^{-2}$ & (0.59, 1.70)$\times 10^{-2}$ & 4.85$\times 10^{-4}$ & -3.21$\times 10^{-3}$ & 2.31$\times 10^{-5}$ & 0.77 & 6.59$\times 10^{-3}$ & (0.03, 1.49)$\times 10^{-2}$ & 4.63$\times 10^{-4}$ & -8.35$\times 10^{-3}$ & 9.15$\times 10^{-5}$ & 0.52\\
  Corr[log(Bilirubin):slope,Platelet:Intercept] & -1.74$\times 10^{-1}$ &( -4.84, 1.38)$\times 10^{-1}$ & 1.18$\times 10^{-2}$ & -4.79$\times 10^{-3}$ & 1.71$\times 10^{-2}$ & 0.98 & -6.44$\times 10^{-2}$ & (-6.81, 5.75)$\times 10^{-1}$ & 1.30$\times 10^{-2}$ & 1.05$\times 10^{-1}$ & 2.88$\times 10^{-2}$ &0.99 \\
  Corr[log(Bilirubin):slope,Platelet:slope] & 1.52$\times 10^{-1}$ & (-1.55, 4.57)$\times 10^{-1}$ & 1.03$\times 10^{-2}$ & 2.67$\times 10^{-2}$ & 1.68$\times 10^{-2}$ & 0.98 & 5.53$\times 10^{-2}$ & (-5.60, 6.60)$\times 10^{-1}$ & 1.29$\times 10^{-2}$ & -6.95$\times 10^{-2}$ & 2.98$\times 10^{-2}$ & 0.99 \\
  Corr[log(Bilirubin):slope,Blood Vessel Malformations:Intercept] & 1.22$\times 10^{-2}$ & (-3.70, 3.95)$\times 10^{-1}$ & 1.32$\times 10^{-2}$ & 4.11$\times 10^{-3}$ & 2.68$\times 10^{-2}$ & 0.97 & 8.85$\times 10^{-3}$ &( -6.55,6.71)$\times 10^{-1}$ & 1.45$\times 10^{-2}$ & 7.24$\times 10^{-4}$ & 3.95$\times 10^{-2}$ & 0.98 \\
  &  \multicolumn{12}{c}{\textbf{Platelet Count}} \\
  E[Platelet:Intercept] & 5.54 & (5.49, 5.59) & 1.56$\times 10^{-3}$ & -1.43$\times 10^{-4}$ & 6.70$\times 10^{-4}$ & 0.94 & 5.46 & (5.36, 5.56) & 3.18$\times 10^{-3}$ & -3.39$\times 10^{-3}$ & 1.98$\times 10^{-3}$ & 0.98 \\
  E[Platelet:slope] & -4.37$\times 10^{-3}$ & (-6.52, -2.23)$\times 10^{-3}$ & 7.00$\times 10^{-5}$ & -7.29$\times 10^{-5}$ & 1.08$\times 10^{-6}$ & 0.94 & -1.13$\times 10^{-2}$ & (-1.58, -0.69)$\times 10^{-2}$ & 1.43$\times 10^{-4}$ & 6.08$\times 10^{-5}$ & 4.69$\times 10^{-6}$ & 0.97 \\
  SD[Platelet:Intercept] & 3.46$\times 10^{-1}$ & (3.11, 3.81)$\times 10^{-1}$ & 1.14$\times 10^{-3}$ & 8.28$\times 10^{-4}$ & 2.31$\times 10^{-4}$ & 0.99 & 3.57$\times 10^{-1}$ &( 2.87, 4.32)$\times 10^{-1}$ & 2.36$\times 10^{-3}$ & 1.22$\times 10^{-2}$ & 1.34$\times 10^{-3}$ & 0.98 \\
  Corr[Platelet:Intercept,Platelet:slope]& 4.56$\times 10^{-2}$ & (-0.97, 1.88)$\times 10^{-1}$ & 4.63$\times 10^{-3}$ & -1.58$\times 10^{-2}$ & 5.14$\times 10^{-3}$ & 0.96 & 5.86$\times 10^{-2}$ & (-2.20, 3.35)$\times 10^{-1}$ & 9.13$\times 10^{-3}$ & -2.86$\times 10^{-3}$ & 1.85$\times 10^{-2}$ & 0.96 \\
  Corr[Platelet:Intercept,Blood vessel malformations:Intercept] & -2.31$\times 10^{-1}$ & (-4.15, -0.44)$\times 10^{-1}$ & 6.19$\times 10^{-3}$ & 1.75$\times 10^{-2}$ & 9.42$\times 10^{-3}$ & 0.96  & -2.38$\times 10^{-1}$ & (-5.53, 0.87)$\times 10^{-1}$ & 1.05$\times 10^{-2}$ & 9.76$\times 10^{-3}$ & 2.27$\times 10^{-2}$ & 0.95\\
  SD[Platelet:slope] & 1.52$\times 10^{-2}$ & (1.36, 1.68)$\times 10^{-2}$ & 5.20$\times 10^{-5}$ & 3.84$\times 10^{-5}$ & 8.05$\times 10^{-7}$ & 0.92 & 1.56$\times 10^{-2}$ &( 1.24, 1.90)$\times 10^{-2}$ & 1.08$\times 10^{-4}$ & 4.31$\times 10^{-4}$ & 3.10$\times 10^{-6}$ & 0.95 \\
  Corr[Platelet:slope,Blood vessel malformations:Intercept] & -8.08$\times 10^{-2}$ & (-2.76, 1.15)$\times 10^{-1}$ & 6.38$\times 10^{-3}$ & -5.01$\times 10^{-4}$ & 8.81$\times 10^{-3}$ & 0.97 & -7.94$\times 10^{-2}$ & (-4.15, 2.60)$\times 10^{-1}$ & 1.11$\times 10^{-2}$ & 8.85$\times 10^{-4}$ & 2.82$\times 10^{-2}$ & 0.96\\
  &  \multicolumn{12}{c}{\textbf{Blood vessel malformations}} \\
  E[Blood vessel malformations:Intercept] & -2.53 & (-3.10, -1.99) & 1.91$\times 10^{-2}$ & 1.59$\times 10^{-2}$ & 6.86$\times 10^{-2}$ & 0.96 & -5.63$\times 10^{-1}$ &( -1.37, 0.23) & 2.60$\times 10^{-2}$ & 1.17$\times 10^{-1}$ & 2.08$\times 10^{-1}$ & 0.92 \\
  E[Blood vessel malformations:Slope] & 1.44$\times 10^{-2}$ & (-0.94, 3.83)$\times 10^{-2}$ & 7.85$\times 10^{-4}$ & -1.92$\times 10^{-4}$ & 1.16$\times 10^{-4}$ & 0.98 & 4.23$\times 10^{-2}$ & (0.25, 8.24)$\times 10^{-2}$ & 1.35$\times 10^{-3}$ & -5.77$\times 10^{-3}$ & 4.03$\times 10^{-4}$ & 0.95 \\
  SD[Blood vessel malformations:Intercept] & 1.87 & (1.38, 2.39) & 1.82$\times 10^{-2}$ & -7.58$\times 10^{-3}$ & 7.38$\times 10^{-2}$ & 0.94 & 1.87 & (1.06,2.75) & 3.37$\times 10^{-2}$ & -9.05$\times 10^{-3}$ & 2.72$\times 10^{-1}$ & 0.88\\
  \hline
  \end{tabularx}
\end{sidewaystable}
 \end{document}
```